# Parsing xml data from website

Tags: php, html, parsing

I want to be able to retrieve the data on a certain site with the font size="6"
I plan on doing this with the xml parser but so far have had no luck. This is my code, if anyone knows where my mistake is, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
@$doc=new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html4);
    $xml=simplexml_import_dom($doc); // just to make xpath more simple

 $data=$xml->xpath('//font size=6'); 
 $arr= array();
foreach ($data as $img) {

         echo $img;

    }
```

Comment: are you searching for the "font" tag having a "size" attribute with a value of 6?

Comment: HTML doesn't have to be valid XML. Having a very strict XML parser will not work. You're probably better off using a regular expression.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Clearly you haven't seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/384808

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html4);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$data = $xpath->query("*/font[@size='6']");
```

Comment: it gives me the following Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : font in Entity, line: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/retrieve.php on line 326
any suggestions?
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/retrieve.php on line 326

Comment: @Teddy13 You're getting that error because your HTML is not valid XML. Since HTML doesn't necessarily need to be valid XML, the only way to avoid that warning is to change the HTML so that it is valid XML (e.g. XHTML)

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Sorry I am not understanding what you are suggesting. How would you go about retrieving then font size="6"? thanks